# How to replace dataframe columns on given condition?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a Dataframe , in which i have two columns, first_columns and second_columns.  first_columns is id and second_columns is room number.
[image]

As you can see from pic that, particular id person serve on different room number. Now i want to replace all the second_columns columns with 1 and zero on given condition

1) if particular first_columns column id person does't not serve in 9, 10 and 11, then replace all the room number with 1, if he work then replace all room number with 0.

In above picture, first_columns id 3737 doest not work in room 9,10, and 11. then all the row of 3737 room number will be replace by 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think need [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) with [`transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.transform.html) for compare by `set`s, last invert mask by `~` and convert to integers:

```
df['new'] = ((~df.groupby('first_column')['second_column']
                .transform(lambda x: set(x) >=set([9,10,11])))
                .astype(int))
print (df)
    first_column  second_column  new
0           3767              2    1
1           3767              4    1
2           3767              6    1
3           6282              2    0
4           6282              9    0
5           6282             10    0
6           6282             11    0
7          10622              0    1
8          13096              7    1
9          13096             10    1
10         13896             11    1
```

Comment: It helped, need one more help from you for my next step.After doing this, Now i wanted to remove all those row, which is having room number 8,9,10 and 11

Comment: @ImranAhmadGhazali - Do you think `df = df[~df['second_column'].isin([8,9,10,11])]` ?

Comment: nicely worked, will you reference me some link from where you get this much knowledge?

Comment: @ImranAhmadGhazali Hmmm, I learn mainly by answering in SO, but I like [Modern pandas tutorial](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/tutorials.html#modern-pandas). Nice day!

Comment: need one more help, suppose i want check if  week 9, 10 and 11 data is not provided, we label this
 as “1” otherwise “0”, this is little hard condition.exam   so , if particular person work on 9th week ,but not 10th and 11th,so it will be zero.So it is not "OR" in 9, 10, and 11. it is "AND". in your comment,13096 person is not working on 9, it that condition is not satisfied, so its lebel should be 0,not 1

Comment: Total means that, if he work any of the three room, he should be assign zero

Comment: @Imran Ahmad Ghazali Now I am offline, on phone only, so better is if create new question. Thank you.